# Yammer Embed open graph bad request

Tags: yammer

We have the below code for enabling intranet comments on some articles. For some users in some articles, we get bad request (error 400). The user has the needed license and can access the Yammer group where the comment is supposed to be posted to.

```javascript
yam.connect.embedFeed({
                container: ".news-social",
                network: Constants.YammerNetwork,
                feedType: "open-graph",
                objectProperties: {
                    url: window.location.href,
                    title: newsArticleValues.Title,
                    image: yammerImage
                },
                config: {
                    promptText: "Comment on this article",
                    use_sso: true,
                    header: false,
                    defaultGroupId: Constants.DefaultYammerGroupId
                }
            });
```

We couldn't reproduce this on our test / staging tenant - only on prod tenant.

The title OG tag in the objectProperties object is with Cyrillic characters which as we expected are encoded in the URL of the Yammer iframe.

Has anyone else experienced such issue?